# Python : Dataframe add a column on index rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Got a dataframe like below, its index is [date,assetName]

How do I add a new column with the open price in 10 days ?

Datatype for date index column is

Timestamp('2007-02-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Feb 1 2007', '%b %d %Y')

market_df   = pd.DataFrame({'date': [
                                    datetime.strptime('Feb 1 2007', '%b %d %Y')
                                    ,datetime.strptime('Feb 1 2007', '%b %d %Y')
                                    ,datetime.strptime('Feb 1 2007', '%b %d %Y') 
                                    ,datetime.strptime('Feb 11 2007', '%b %d %Y')
                                    ,datetime.strptime('Feb 11 2007', '%b %d %Y')
                                    ,datetime.strptime('Feb 11 2007', '%b %d %Y') 
                                    ],
                            'assetName': ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'AMZN','AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'AMZN'],
                            'open': [20, 30.9, 40, 22.3, 35, 45],
                            'close': [20.5, 30.6, 40.5,22.3,35,45],
                           })
market_df = market_df.set_index(['date','assetName'])
```

How do I get this dataframe with a new column "price_in_10_days"

```
date    assetName   open    close   price_in_10_days
2007-02-01  AAPL    20.0    20.5    22.3
2007-02-01  GOOGL   30.9    30.6    35.0
2007-02-01  AMZN    40.0    40.5    45.0
2007-02-11  AAPL    22.3    22.3    NaN
2007-02-11  GOOGL   35.0    35.0    NaN
2007-02-11  AMZN    45.0    45.0    NaN
```

[image: Data Frame Sample]

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It's really unclear what are you asking for, however, if the question is how to append a new column to your Dataframe given that you have MultiIndex, then the answer would be that it doesn't really matter, a simple `df['open in 10 days'] = pd.Series(data=[])` will do as long as the new column data has the same length as your df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need create `DatetimeIndex` by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) by `10` days and last [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
market_df['price_in_10_days']  = market_df['open'].unstack().shift(-1, freq='10D').stack()
print (market_df)

                      open  close  price_in_10_days
date       assetName                               
2007-02-01 AAPL       20.0   20.5              22.3
           GOOGL      30.9   30.6              35.0
           AMZN       40.0   40.5              45.0
2007-02-11 AAPL       22.3   22.3               NaN
           GOOGL      35.0   35.0               NaN
           AMZN       45.0   45.0               NaN
```